# I’m struggling to verify a bsc contract that I have created with solidiy

Tags: contract-deployment

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract Token {
  mapping(address => uint) public balances;
  mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;
  uint public totalSupply = 10000 * 10 ** 18;
  string public name = "My Token";
  string public symbol = "TKN";
  uint public decimals = 18;

  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);

  constructor() {
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
  }

  function balanceOf(address owner) public returns(uint) {
    return balances[owner];
  }

  function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
    require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
    balances[to] += value;
    balances[msg.sender] -= value;
   emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
    return true;
  }

  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
    require(balanceOf(from) >= value, 'balance too low');
    require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, 'allowance too low');
    balances[to] += value;
    balances[from] -= value;
    emit Transfer(from, to, value);
    return true;   
  }

  function approve(address spender, uint value) public returns (bool) {
    allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
    return true;   
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain with details the problem?

Comment: I am not sure what is the issue? What is the specific issue that has to be solved?